# how to get notification at specific time in android oreo and above when app is completely killed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get local notification at specific time in android device, its work good below then android version 8 but i am not able to get notification in android oreo when app is killed from memory. I try this with broadcast receiver and service but no working? Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Job Service for this

```
 ​<service
           ​android:name=".TestJobService"
           ​android:label="Word service"
           ​android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >

</service
```

Utils Class

```
import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;

public class Util {

    // schedule the start of the service every 10 - 30 seconds
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        //builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        //builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        //builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }

}




import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Util.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

Register the receiver in the Android manifest for the BOOT_COMPLETED event.

```
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * JobService to be scheduled by the JobScheduler.
 * start another service
 */
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalWordService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share any sample project please??? i really need that